# How to remove permission from a role only for a particular user in spatie/laravel-permission?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

Let's say that I have three users in my system `Sam`, `John` and `Sarah`.
All three have a role of `editor` which gives them permission to `create article`, `edit article`, `publish article` and `delete article`.
Now for some reason, I don't want `Sam` to have permission to `delete article` but still have the role of `editor`.

How can I achieve this in Laravel with this spatie/laravel-permission package?
(Assume that I may have to do such operation on a somewhat regular basis and there are after some time I may assign back `delete article` again the `Sam`. And there are way too many permissions in any role, so i can't do it manually.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom policies.

In the Policy you set an exception for your user or group of users.

To create and save your policy.(https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#creating-policies)

Example Policy

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ArticlePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;


    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the article.
     *
     * @param  \App\User $user
     * @param  \App\Post $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Article $article)
    {
        // retrieve the user as you wish.
        // I just did a check with his name but it is preferable to have a more 
        // advanced identification.

        if ($user->name = 'SAM')) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($user->can('delete article')) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```